# OSX Pillow Incompatible library version libtiff.5.dylib & libjpeg.8.dylib

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

I've got this error while trying to use Pilow on any scripts:

```
  File "/Users/antonio/WWW/myproj/myproj/functions.py", line 12, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageOps
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 53, in <module>
    from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libtiff.5.dylib requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 9.0.0
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and i had to reinstall pillow and all is dependencies. 
Some of my symlink where not good.

First you have to make:

```
brew doctor
```

And see if you have some errors. Mine was like this :

```
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libpng.3.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libpng12.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libpng14.14.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.la
/usr/local/lib/libpng12.la
/usr/local/lib/libpng14.la
/usr/local/lib/libpng15.la

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

 Unexpected .pc files:
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpng12.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpng14.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a
/usr/local/lib/libpng12.a
/usr/local/lib/libpng14.a
```

So i decided to clean all errors and dependencies i have installed:

```
brew uninstall pillow
brew uninstall libpng
brew uninstall libjpeg
brew uninstall webp
brew uninstall libtiff
brew uninstall littlecms

brew prune => to clean symlink
```

When my brew doctor was without any errors i just run `brew install pillow` and all was working fine.

Hope it's help.

Comment: brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2 , install again

Comment: Faced similar issue because python was looking for libraries in DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH first instead of anaconda directory. "unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" helped to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Try reinstall latest version pillow. I use anaconda python, and

```
conda install -f pillow
```

fix a similar problem for me.

Comment: This is not a good answer. Using `pip install` works for me, but using pip or conda won't work if there are problems with libraries elsewhere on the system

Comment: I use anaconda and this answer worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar problem on OSX 10.10.2.  I also use anaconda for python, Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (x86_64).  The answers by Frank and user4183543 were good things to try but they **did not work for me**.

Creating softlinks to the unloaded libraries worked for me.

I did:

```
$ locate libtiff.5.dylib
```

and among the results was

```
/Users/curt/anaconda/lib/libtiff.5.dylib
/Users/curt/anaconda/pkgs/libtiff-4.0.2-1/lib/libtiff.5.dylib
```

Results for `libjpeg.8.dylib` were analogous.  I made softlinks for both `libjpeg.8.dylib` and `libtiff.5.dylib` via these commands:

```
$ ln -s /Users/curt/anaconda/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
$ ln -s /Users/curt/anaconda/lib/libtiff.5.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib
```

Pillow / PIL is now working for me, at least for the time being.

I'm sure there is a better solution that identifies what the core problem is but I'm posting this for the benefit of conda users who might be experiencing similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

If you use conda try:

```
conda install libtiff
```

Or if you don't, try:

```
pip install --upgrade libtiff
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. Since I installed Python using Anaconda, "conda install Pillow did work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, fixed it with following:

```
brew reinstall libtiff && brew reinstall gd
```

Comment: Yeah, I just spent half a day on this issue.  The latest versions of OSX (Sonoma) require making sure that you have everything up to date in Homebrew and/or Conda.  Then the libtiff library will install and work correctly.