# ImportError: [...] Library not loaded [...] Reason: Incompatible library version

Tags: python-imaging-library, scikit-image, libtiff

I just downloaded scikit-image and I got an error message by simply trying to import the packages to run a tutorial example of the scikit website (["Gabor filter banks for texture classification"](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_gabor.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-features-detection-plot-gabor-py)). See error message below.

I re-installed libtiff (using pip and homebrew) and Pillow (using conda), following the advice of some scikit-image developers. But the problem persists. I have the latest version of pillow installed (4.2.1), and I made sure to uninstall PIL before, and to build pillow from source to install all the dependencies.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6205bd0cfb9d> in <module>()
      5 from scipy import ndimage as ndi
      6 
----> 7 from skimage import data
      8 from skimage.util import img_as_float
      9 from skimage.filters import gabor_kernel

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/data/__init__.py in <module>()
     14 
     15 from .. import data_dir
---> 16 from ..io import imread, use_plugin
     17 from .._shared._warnings import expected_warnings
     18 from ._binary_blobs import binary_blobs

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/io/__init__.py in <module>()
      5 """
      6 
----> 7 from .manage_plugins import *
      8 from .sift import *
      9 from .collection import *

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py in <module>()
     26 from glob import glob
     27 
---> 28 from .collection import imread_collection_wrapper
     29 
     30 

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/io/collection.py in <module>()
     10 import numpy as np
     11 import six
---> 12 from PIL import Image
     13 
     14 from ..external.tifffile import TiffFile

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in <module>()
     54     # Also note that Image.core is not a publicly documented interface,
     55     # and should be considered private and subject to change.
---> 56     from . import _imaging as core
     57     if PILLOW_VERSION != getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None):
     58         raise ImportError("The _imaging extension was built for another "

ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libtiff.5.dylib
Referenced from: /Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/PIL/_imaging.so
Reason: Incompatible library version: _imaging.so requires version 8.0.0 or 
later, but libtiff.5.dylib provides version 7.0.0
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: This is not a scikit-image bug.  Please re-install Anaconda.

Comment: I am not going to re-install Anaconda. It's too dramatic. I have been working with Numpy, Scipy, Scikit-Learn, Brian2 etc., and it works totally fine. What easy fix can I do? Thanks

Comment: Do any of these answers help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728468/osx-pillow-incompatible-library-version-libtiff-5-dylib-libjpeg-8-dylib

Comment: You should also create a new conda environment with Python 3.6 and work there. ;)